# rails validating the number of users on the account model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an app where a user has many accounts and an account has one user.  I'm trying to create a setup where an account manager can add a user from the database by entering their e-mail address or if someone is not already a user they are added to the database and then added to the account.  I want to limit the number of users that can be added to each account.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to account
  validates_each :account do |user, attr, value|
    user.errors.add attr, "too many users for account" if user.account.users.size >= 6
  end
end
```

I found a great validation resource here: [Best practice for limiting the number of associations within a has_many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292403/best-practice-for-limiting-the-number-of-associations-within-a-has-many-relation)  This works great for limiting the number of users but when I try to create a new user (either entering an unknown email or from the normal sign up path) it throws the error

```
undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass
```

I also have an add_user controller to control how users are added to the account

```
class AddUsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
     @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
    if @user 
        @user.add_user_to_account(params[:account_id])
        flash[:info] =  "Added User to Account"
        redirect_to accounts_url
    else 
      email = params[:user][:email]
      generated_password = rand_password=('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(8).join
      @user = User.new(:name => "New User", :email => email, :password => generated_password, :password_confirmation => generated_password )
      @user.save
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.add_user_to_account(params[:account_id])
      @user.send_lab_invited_email
        flash[:info] = "Email sent to user"
        redirect_to accounts_url
    end 
  end

  def update
  end  

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:account_id, :user_id)
    end

    def get_user
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    end
end
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that the user doesn't have an account so it can't find the account.users but most users won't have accounts until they are assigned one by the account manager.  Can anyone shed light on how I can fix this issue?  Can I write an if statement in the model like if current user or maybe instead define the validation in the AddUser Controller?

UPDATE:
This is my add_user_to_account method

```
  def add_user_to_account(account_id)
    update_attributes(account_id: account_id)
  end
```

Comment: First thing. If the user has only one account (belongs_to :account) why do you validates each?

Secondly, it is permitted to the user not have an account (This is a possible situation?)

Comment: Most users will start without an account.   The account will usually be assigned to the user later.  The validation is needed because accounts can have many users.  So what I'm trying to validate is the number of users on an account.

Comment: We'll my answer is there to help, but maybe you should think where this validation is really needed. I mean, the maximum users per account is a validation for account, not for the user. Take some time to think about this, and how you're coupling this two models (Single Responsibility Principle)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validates_each :account do |user, attr, value|
  user.errors.add attr, "too many users for account" if value.users.size >= 6  
end
```

Comment: now the error is undefined method `sers' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Sorry, I have mistake in my post: not 'sers' - must be 'users'

Comment: I'm still getting the error undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Because when you save new user in first time account is not set! You may try go up @user.add_user_to_account(params[:account_id]) before save, but it's depend of what implement in add_user_to_account.

Comment: That could work for users added by account managers but most users will be created through the normal sign up path and some will never get an account id.  Is there a way to validate the number of users on an account without requiring each user to have an account?  Like only validate user if ... or add the validation in the controller?

Comment: I don't understand why you set account after save? Why you don't user something like this:  user = User.new(users_params) and after generate password: user.password = generated_password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105837/discussion-between-railsie-and-kunashir).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you don't need `validates_each` since you're validating only one field.

Secondly, you can add a [`if` option to the validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).

So what you want is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to account
  validates :maximum_users_per_account if: :account

  ... Your code ...

  private
  def maximum_users_per_account
    errors.add :account, "too many users for account" if user.account.users.count >= 6
  end
end
```